# Neo4j Cypher UNWIND keys

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to create the following query:

```
MATCH (v:Value) 
WHERE v.id = {valueId} 
UNWIND keys(v) AS key 
WITH v, key 
WHERE key CONTAINS 'property.' 
REMOVE key
```

but it fails right now with the following error:

```
org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Unexpected end of input: expected an identifier character, whitespace, node labels, '{', a property map, a relationship pattern, '.' or '(' (line 1, column 122 (offset: 121))
"MATCH (v:Value) WHERE v.id = {valueId} WITH v UNWIND keys(v) AS key WITH v, key WHERE key CONTAINS 'property.' REMOVE key"
                                                                                                                         ^
```

What is wrong with this query and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not the UNWIND on the keys, the issue is that you specify to remove something not on a graph object.

Ideally this would have to become :

```
MATCH (v:Value) 
WHERE v.id = {valueId} 
UNWIND keys(v) AS key 
WITH v, key 
WHERE key CONTAINS 'property.' 
REMOVE v.key
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work as the property key cannot be variable.

A workaround with APOC is to set a cleaned map on the node :

```
MATCH (v:Value) 
WHERE v.id = {valueId} 
SET v = apoc.map.clean(properties(v), filter(x IN keys(v) WHERE x CONTAINS 'property.'), [])
RETURN v
```